# If $X$ is a continuous random variable with support $A$, does this imply that the cdf of $X$ is strictly increasing on $A$?

Tags: random-variable, continuous-data, cumulative-distribution-function

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with support $A$, does this imply that the cdf of $X$ is strictly increasing on $A$?

My guess is yes. But just in case, let me know if you can think of any counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counter example is made by taking the cdf as the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) $\mathfrak c(\cdot)$ on $[0,1]$, whose support is the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $\mathfrak C$:

1. it is a continuous (if not absolutely continuous) distribution
2. its support $\mathfrak C$ is closed and of Lebesgue measure zero
3. the points 1⁄3 and 2⁄3 are adjacent in $\mathfrak C$, i.e., $\mathfrak C\cap(1/3,2/3)=\emptyset$ while $1/3,2/3\in\mathfrak C$
4. hence $\mathfrak c(1/3)=\mathfrak c(2/3)$ and $\mathfrak c(\cdot)$ is not strictly increasing on $\mathfrak C$

Comment: Brilliant counter-example. What happens if the density exists as discussed in the other answer?

Comment: @Cross Wherever the density might be zero, the cdf is not strictly increasing. It is possible for densities to equal zero on the support of the random variable--they just cannot be zero throughout any open interval.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an! This is very helpful.

Comment: @Xi'an@whuber Then requiring the density to be everywhere positive would suffice, right?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the density exists, and ignoring the boundary points, a function strictly increases if its derivative is strictly positive. CDF’s derivative is PDF and it is strictly positive in the support. So, CDF must strictly increase in the support.

Comment: A continuous random variable being a random variable whose cumulative distribution function (cdf) is continuous everywhere, this cdf may be differentiable nowhere, meaning there is no density (pdf).

Comment: @gunes Thank you very much!